# switch NULL values in SQL complex

Tags: sql, null

Hey I've got this query:

```
 select
   MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 1 THEN AnswerDate END) AS FinalAnswerDate,
   MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 2 THEN AnswerDate END) AS StartAnswerDate
from some_table
```

Now, What I wish is that when StartAnswerDate is NULL so it will copy whatever it is in the cell of FinalAnswerDate.

the idea is that sometimes there is a final answer date without start answer date so right now it shows the final answer date (timestamp) and on the start date it shows NULL.

when there is no start date and only final date I want the start date to show the same as final (because when it started and finished is at the same time).

basically, swtich the NULL values to the one in the cell near by..

now it shows:

```
FinalAnswerDate                     StartAnswerDate        
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2022-05-03 10:00:00                NULL                    (*because there is no start answer date, only final)
 2022-05-03 09:09:00                2022-05-03 08:34:00     (ex of start answer date different from final)
```

what I want:

```
  FinalAnswerDate                     StartAnswerDate        
------------------------------------------------------------------
 2022-05-03 10:00:00                2022-05-03 10:00:00   (same date as final)                    
 2022-05-03 09:09:00                2022-05-03 08:34:00
```

Comment: Please add which RDMS as well in the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
SELECT
    FinalAnswerDate,
    CASE WHEN StartAnswerDate IS NOT NULL THEN StartAnswerDate ELSE FinalAnswerDate END AS StartAnswerDate
FROM (SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 1 THEN AnswerDate END) AS FinalAnswerDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 2 THEN AnswerDate END) AS StartAnswerDate
FROM some_table) AS T
```

Or without subselect but this might be less performing:

```
SELECT
   MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 1 THEN AnswerDate END) AS FinalAnswerDate,
   CASE WHEN (MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 2 THEN AnswerDate END) IS NOT NULL) THEN MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 2 THEN AnswerDate END) ELSE (MAX(CASE WHEN ConsultationStatus = 1 THEN AnswerDate END)) END AS StartAnswerDate
FROM some_table
```

Maybe there is better way to do this.

Comment: Hey, maybe there's a better solution? with your suggestion it eliminates the option of start date different from final date and when I have final date it simply copies it to start date without showing the option that there was a start date. I want that to happened only when the start date in NULL